# How to write a query with a AND condition as part of ContentResolver query - Android Content Provider

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-contentresolver

I have this content resolver query which translates to `select * from book where favflag = 1`.

But now I want to change it so that it translate to `select * from book where favflag = 1 AND bookid = 2;`

How do I achieve this?

Here is the content resolver query:

```
Cursor BookCursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(
    BookContract.BookEntry.CONTENT_URI,
    null,
    BookContract.BookEntry.COLUMNFAVFLAG + " = ?",
    new String[]{"1"},
    null);
```

Answer (score 4):

Since there is no `BookContract` in the Android SDK that I am aware of, I assume this is your own class. In that case, we do not know the API of that class.

With that in mind, try:

```
Cursor BookCursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(
  BookContract.BookEntry.CONTENT_URI,
  null,
  BookContract.BookEntry.COLUMNFAVFLAG + " = ? AND "+BookContract.BookEntry.COLUMNID + " = ?",
  new String[]{"1", "2"},
  null);
```

Substitute in the proper value for `BookContract.BookEntry.COLUMNID`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Cursor BookCursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(
    BookContract.BookEntry.CONTENT_URI,
    null,
    BookContract.BookEntry.COLUMNFAVFLAG + " = ? AND "+BookContract.BookEntry.COLUMNBOOKID + " = ?", // Use your variable here in place of COLUMNBOOKID
    new String[]{"1", "2"},
    null);
```